# Nmaximize error : The function value Indeterminate is not a number at

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have been looking on the StackExchange for solutions to my issue... but I can't find. So I am asking for a solution to the following problem:

First I define some functions, the function to be maximized, V, the parameters and then the NMaximize function for given values of a parameter h and the constraints.
I get some results but also the following message :
Nmaximize error : The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {0.554465,1.91298,3.00862,4.06643*10^-6,0.}
The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {1.63675,0.,1.02183,0.167442,0.231841}
The function value Indeterminate is not a number at {0.0972852,1.26903,2.63931,1.6129,0.}
Further output of NMaximize:: nnum will be supressed during this calculation.

Could you help me with this program ? Am I doing something wrong ?

```
G[P_] := 0.1 + γ/(1 + γ P);
B[P_] := 0.125 - β/(1 + β P);
q = (2 n (1 - h))/Q;
A[P_] := B[P] + q;
L[s_] := n (1 - θ (1 - s))*(1 - h);
F[x_, y_] := x^ϵ y^(1 - ϵ);
Cons1[k_, s_, c_, d_] := F[k, L[s]] - n (c + d) - k;
Cons2[k_, P_, s_] := P - η/δ F[k, L[s]];
Cons3[s_, P_] := n*s - n*G[P]/A[P]; 

V[c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ, P_?NumericQ] := 
 n u[c, s] + ζ n u[d, s];

n = 40000; γ = 0.005; β = 0.005; Q = 150000; ϵ \
= 0.3; η = 0.1; δ = 0.05; ζ = 0.9; σ = 0.2;
θ = 0.1;


lockdown = {h, 0, 0.9, 0.05};

 
OutMax1 = 
  Table[Maximize[{Abs[V[c, d, s, k, P]]}, {c, d, s, k, P} ∈ 
     ImplicitRegion[{c >= 0 && d >= 0 && k >= 0 && P >= 0 && s >= 0 &&
         1 > s && Cons1[k, s, c, d] == 0 && Cons2[k, P, s] == 0 && 
        Cons3[s, P] == 0 }, {c, d, s, k, P}]], Evaluate[lockdown]];
```

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE].  The code you've provided is incomplete;  what is the function `u[c,s]`?  Also, your code uses `Maximize`, but your question refers to `NMaximize`;  is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: More broadly, the error message you're getting is telling you that your function `V` is returning the value `Indeterminate` (i.e., something like 0/0 or $0^\infty$) when it's being called at certain values of its arguments.    It's not a fatal error, necessarily, but it does indicate that you need to understand your objective function better.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the definition for the function `u`

Comment: Thanks for your answers.. I am sorry I forget to precise the function u: ```u[m_,f_]:=Log[m]+\[sigma]Log[f]```

Comment: c,d, and s all have constraints >= 0 but because of the logarithms in your function u, you need to ensure there is a small minimum non-zero value `s >= 10^-9, c >= 10^-9, d>=10^-9` for example. The bigger problem is _why_ maximize wants to explore these extreme values.

Comment: Thanks @flinty for your answer. You're right, there is an issue since Log[0]->-infinity. Indeed, the results I obtained with the program above also violates the constraints I suppose....Indeed, I have tried to ensure a small minimum non-zero value for the variables s, c and d as you suggested but still it doesn't work.